# picking and writing out some fractions of list with for-loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, writefile

There is a dataset as a `csv-file` which contains some tabular of data.
I want to pick out the fractions with the same number.
For example i have one list

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6]
```

and i want a loop, which writes `text-files` with the same numbers
file_1.txt contains `1,1`
file_2.txt contains `2,2`
file_3.txt contains `3,3`
file_4.txt contains `4,4,4`
file_5.txt contains `5,5,5,5`
file_6.txt contains `6`

I still have no real result, because so far everything is wrong.

Comment: Even if your result is wrong and does not seem to work, please share with us your attempt.

Comment: do you expect the output to repeat the same number n times? Or do you just want to get the count for each element?

Comment: @Felk: The desired output seems to be clear here if you look at `a`. The point is his/her attempt

Comment: Look into `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much cleaner approach would be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48476719/1672429) and [`str.join`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497773/5858851):

```
from itertools import groupby

for num, group in groupby(a):
    filename = "file_%d.txt"%num
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(",".join(map(str, group)) + "\n")
```

Another important point is that you [should always use the `with` statement when reading and writing to files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012921/5858851).

---

Using `groupby` assumes that the data is already sorted. Another approach would be to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

for num, count in Counter(a).items():
    filename = "file_%d.txt"%num
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(",".join([str(num)]*count) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should work:

```
for x in set(a):
    text_file = open("file_"+str(x)+".txt", "w")
    text_file.write(((str(x)+',')*a.count(x))[:-1])
    text_file.close()
```

Where that `[:-1]` in the third line is to remove extra comma ;)